# Facebook Tab Not Showing on Client's Browser but Displaying Everywhere Else

Tags: facebook, api

I have a Facebook tab I created for a client which displays fine on my end. I have also tested it in Adobe Browser Lab and it displays correctly on all major browsers. The link is here:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Jamillah-David-Perfect-Combination/477059612333664?sk=app_425472224179980

When my clients goes to see the page I've made for them, they get no output of content. Here's a screenshot they sent me (nevermind that they highlighted everything, you can see that there is no output):

[image: Screenshot]

The SSL and non-SSL versions both work. The Sandbox mode is disabled. I'm not sure what the next step is to troubleshoot this. I had them go to the site that the tab is hosted on which is:

http://www.miller-media.com/sites/lambs/videos.html

This displays fine to them which is odd to me so it has something to do with Facebook displaying it.

Thanks for the help!

### EDIT

Client cleared the cache on the browser and then went to the link and it displayed fine when they were logged out of Facebook. As soon as they logged back in, the tab stopped displaying for them. I've got it narrowed down it being an issue with their actual account being able to view tabs (from what I gather). Are there settings that allow people to view or not view tabs? I can't seem to find them.

### EDIT

Ok, so they still can't view the tab. They gave me their login and I went in and looked at the iFrame app on my computer through their account and it displayed correctly. So it's not an issue with their account and it's not an issue with caching. I've had several people check the iFrame and it works fine (in fact, nobody else is having this problem). This problem persists with tabs I built them. I'm currently having them check the version of Google Chrome they are using (I don't know if this would affect it at all). Any other ideas?

### EDIT

I just went into 'Edit Page' from the main admin menu and clicked on 'Apps' on the left side. I found the problem apps and clicked 'Link to this Tab' and I was given this message "Some content in this message has been reported as abusive by Facebook users." There is no abusive content on these tabs. Is there a reason this would happen? Is it a glitch?

Comment: Not sure if it's a browser caching issue from their side, you can ask them to clear the cache. Also try adding a dummy GET parameter to your URL to avoid the caching: `http://www.miller-media.com/sites/lambs/videos.html?ver=1`

Comment: Ah that's a great idea. I'll try that. The reason I believe that's not the issue is that I had them right click on the empty box and click 'reload frame' to refresh the content and it didn't update it. I'll try this though.

Comment: Ah, the other issue most likely is that appending to the URL will actually break the link is has to Facebook since it will change...

Comment: I don't think 'reload frame' is a hard refresh and hence it may not solve the issue. They still need to clear the cache I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask them to do that on Chrome and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: One question for you, were you able to see the tab displaying properly within the Facebook link I posted above?

Comment: Ok good to know. Thanks. I'm having them clear their cache and then I will back with hopefully a big check mark for you!

Comment: I use chrome, the FB link was a little janky at first, seemed like it was timing out loading the content from Youtube. I reloaded a few times and was unable to repro, it worked fine. Loaded your iframe link directely and that worked fine as well. Both Http and Https seem to work as expected. FYI within chrome use ctrl+shift+r to reload page and break cache.. Have them try that since it's most likely on their end with their browser. GL

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured. When you say that it was janky, do you mean the tab showed up and the YouTube videos didn't load (meaning they just showed black boxes)? Or was the whole tab not loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could easily be related to this (presumably temporary) bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/514963005198830

If your client uses the 'Log in as `<page>`' functionality it's almost certainly due to that bug

Otherwise: if your app is actually receiving a request when the client attempts to load it you should be able to see if there's something strange about the request, or if it's failing before facebook makes the POST request to your server

Comment: Oh wow, that may be it exactly. I'm having them log out and log back in and try the page again through a direct link to see if it's fixed and then I'll give you that bounty if it is. Thanks Igy!